# Button created with jQuery/JS, don't react to click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying create a list of Messages a user can type in an textarea on the site and delete any of them using a button he automatically creates with each message. 
My idea is that I create a div in which I first put the message of the user in and then prepend the button with the same ID of the div; This way I call the ID of the button and remove all elements with the same ID.

```
<script>
var theButtonId = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#commentButton1').click(function() {
    var toAdd = $("textarea#commentTextarea1").val(); //Content to add
    var theId = "dieButtons"+theButtonId.toString(); //creating unique ID

    // Adding first Div      
    $('#targetField').append( 
        $('<div />', {
            id: theId,
            }));
    // Adding content
    $('#'+theId).append(
        $('<div />', {
             text: toAdd
             }));
    //(-----1-----)Adding Button        
    $('#'+theId).prepend(
         $('<button />', {
             type: 'button',
             id: theId,
             class: 'commentButton2',
             text: "-"
             }));
    theButtonId++;
    });
});
//Button Command
$(document).on("ready", function(){
  //(-----2-----)
$('.commentButton2').on("click", function(){  
   var thisId = $(this).attr("id");
       $("#"+thisId).remove();
});
});
</script>
```

It perfectly lists the elements in the #textfield 
I added a button directly in my HTML code which deletes certain divs, as well as itself using the code above. This is why I know that the Problem is that the created Buttons at (-----1-----) don't react to the command in (-----2-----)

I already tried to create an Input of type button and put a .click function instead of .on("click", [...]).

Comment: @Popnoodles the question you linked is also marked as duplicate :)

Comment: `ids` are meant to be unique

Comment: @dreamweiver 
My bad, I just started coding two weeks ago and oversaw this^^' 
Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#buttonid', function() {

});
```

Use event delegation on dynamically created elements

[DOCUMENTATION](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Ah, now I see! It worked finde, thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot guradio. That helped for me too. Eventough, this scenario of dynamic list is very frequent, I have hard time finding a decent bootstrap documentation about this kind of details on how to use bootstrap elements (different scenarios, events, examples, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xcbt3otv/1/)**

Try to use :

```
$('#targetField').on("click",'.commentButton2', function(){
```

Instead of :

```
$('.commentButton2').on("click", function(){
```

It should work.

Comment: It didn't work for me and even blocked the static created buttons..
But got an answer from Pekka, thanks :)